# Getting the equation number as an integer

Tags: fp

I want to use the number of an equation as an integer value. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}\label{b1}
    a+b
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}\label{b2}
    c+d
    \end{equation}

\FPeval{\result}{clip(\ref{b1}+\ref{b2})}
\ref{b1} + \ref{b2} = $\result$\par
\end{document}
```

I expect the result as the following:

> 1 + 2 = 3

How can I achieve this?

Comment: With the `xfp` package you don't need the intermediate step (neither `clip`): `$\ref{b1} + \ref{b2} = \fpeval{\getrefnumber{b1}+\getrefnumber{b2}}$`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `\ref` is not expandable.  You can use `\getrefnumber` from the `refcount` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{refcount}
\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}\label{b1}
    a+b
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}\label{b2}
    c+d
    \end{equation}

\FPeval{\result}{clip(\getrefnumber{b1}+\getrefnumber{b2})}
\ref{b1} + \ref{b2} = $\result$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDITED to use `\ref` in final line, per suggestion of Phelype.

In fact, as long as you are working with integer arithmetic, you can forego the use of `fp` altogether:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcount}
\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}\label{b1}
    a+b
    \end{equation}

    \begin{equation}\label{b2}
    c+d
    \end{equation}

\ref{b1} + \ref{b2} = $\the\numexpr\getrefnumber{b1}+\getrefnumber{b2}\relax$\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: The final line should _probably_ be `\ref` because of eventual hyperlinking (unless explicitly undesired, of course).

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks.  Done.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, Thank you very much.