# Why is there an empty \hbox at the end of the text to which a \ref or \pageref expands?

Tags: ref, pageref

A `\ref` in LaTeX expands to the text of the current label at the point of the corresponding `\label`, followed by an empty `\hbox`.  In LaTeX3 this `\hbox` is an explicit `\null` in the definition of `\\@setref`, so also appears after the page number in an expanded `\pageref`.

Why would you want an empty `\hbox` there?  (It makes it hard to use `\ref` to generate, for example, file names or csnames.)

The `\null` was there in LaTeX2.09, so has been carefully preserved in rewriting

Comment: You can't use `\ref` in any event to construct filenames, because `\ref` is not expandable.  As I recall, there is an expandable alternative...`\usepackage{refcount}` and `\getrefnumber`.

Comment: Perhaps this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518923/getting-the-equation-number-as-an-integer, is a duplicate

Comment: It's not quite a duplicate: the questkon was more about the motivation for putting the \null there.  Likewise, something related to package refcount is what I had been implementing, but I was wondering why \ref itself was not useful in doing so.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see the code:

```
% latex.ltx, line 10226:
\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}}
```

Say we have `\ref{foo}`. The token `\r@foo` is built before expanding `\@setref`, so we get

```
\@setref\r@foo\@firstoftwo{foo}
```

Now let's see the definition of `\@setref`:

```
% latex.ltx, line 10217:
\def\@setref#1#2#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
   \protect\G@refundefinedtrue
   \nfss@text{\reset@font\bfseries ??}%
   \@latex@warning{Reference `#3' on page \thepage \space
             undefined}%
  \else
   \expandafter#2#1\null
  \fi}
```

If the cross reference is not yet resolved, the test `\ifx\r@foo\relax` returns true and it's not the part that interests us. Suppose `\r@foo` is defined; then we get

```
#1 <- \r@foo
#2 <- \@firstoftwo
#3 <- foo
```

and the expansion becomes

```
\expandafter\@firstoftwo\r@foo\null
```

The expansion of `\r@foo` will be something of the form `{1.1}{1}`, where the first braced part is the cross reference and the second part is the page number, so we'd get

```
\@firstoftwo{1.1}{1}\null
```

With `\pageref` it would be essentially the same, but with `\@secondoftwo`.

Why `\null`? It sets the space factor to 1000 and avoids ligatures. Ligatures are not very likely to happen, but you don't want a period at the end of the number to be an end-of-sentence period.

I'm not sure how you'd make control sequences or file names from `\ref`. However, it's not difficult to make an expandable version of `\ref` by changing the “true text” in the `\ifx` so it is really expandable and removing `\null`.

Comment: @campa Try with a trailing period in the reference number.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying that, but I was trying it the wrong way. Now I get it...

Comment: Yes, that'll be it.  Trailing full stops and unlikely ligatures sounds convincing.  Thanks.